# Missing image uploaded on firebase storage (Using cloud function to update firestore DB)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I currently building a web application (build with react, nodejs & firebase) where I have a form where users can upload an image and fill in other information.

When the user submits the form:

- other information will be stored directly in the firebase firestore.
- The image will be uploaded to firebase storage. Only after that, my cloud function will listen to that event and update the collection accordingly with the image URL.

Below is roughly the code. No issue with this.

```
exports.onFileUploaded = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async obj => {
  // embed new file url
  return firestore
    .collection("user")
    .doc(docId)
    .update({
      image: fileURL
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
})
```

The problem is, for some occasions, I found out the document on storage is updated with the image URL, but the object is not found on the storage. Technically it won't be possible because the only way a document got an image URL is after the cloud function listens to an event that a file is uploaded to storage.

Do you guys have any clue what should I do to fix this? Or do you guys have any idea how should I handle this better?

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your image has not been stored? Please double-check by refreshing your browser screen. What happens if you copy and paste the received fileUrl in your browser?

Comment: Can you show the code corresponding to "embed new file url"??

Answer (score 0):

Following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvnETnRViFY) that suits your example, I can see that instead of doing it all at once, it is advisable to do it step by step confirming the success of each step with a onSuccess() which will prevent concurrency that might lead to what you're experiencing.

You can see example of their videos that will include the aforementioned resource [here](https://github.com/discospiff/MyPlantDiaryQ).